# Unexpected keyword 'this' reactjs jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new to reactjs. I'm trying to put a condition in the render return method to show component.
I'm getting the following error.

```
./components/Layouts/Header.js
SyntaxError: /home/user/Desktop/pratap/reactjs/society/society-front/components/Layouts/Header.js: Unexpected keyword 'this' (14:8)

  12 |   render() {
  13 |     return (
> 14 |       { this.props.custom ? <CustomStyle /> : <DefaultStyle /> }
     |         ^
  15 |     );
  16 |   }
  17 | }
```

Here is my component code -

```
import React from "react";
import CustomStyle from "./CustomStyle";
import DefaultStyle from "./DefaultStyle";

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      custom:this.props.custom
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      { this.props.custom ? <CustomStyle /> : <DefaultStyle /> }
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't return a ternary operator when you are explicitly returning `JSX`,  Wrap your code in a `Fragment`:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <>{ this.props.custom ? <CustomStyle /> : <DefaultStyle /> }</>
    );
  }
```

Or remove the separator:

```
render(){
    return this.props.custom ? <CustomStyle /> : <DefaultStyle />
}
```

Comment: remove the separator is a better approach other than using ugly Fragment. thanks